# Play video one after another

Tags: android, android-videoview

I need to play two video one after another(as a pair), the first video is as intro video and the second video is as main video, So what I actually need is that after finishing intro video the main video will start...say intro-1 & main-1, intro-2&main-2, intro-3& main3...so on.
 the problem that I am getting is that i cnt move to intro video again after completing the main video.Only the main video is played again and again

Here is that code:

```
      videoView.setVideoPath(introPath);
        videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.start();


    videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

                public void onCompletion(final MediaPlayer mp) {
                        videoView.setVideoPath(mainPath);
                        MediaController mc = new MediaController(DisplayVideo.this);
                        videoView.requestFocus();
                        videoView.start();
                        }
                        }
```

any help will really be appreciated Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a list of the video paths, something like:

```
List<String> videoPathes = new ArrayList<String>();
videoPathes.add(path1);
videoPathes.add(path2);
// etc..
```

and some index, for example:

```
int i = 0;
```

In the onCompletionListener, set the next path this way:

```
public void onCompletion(final MediaPlayer mp) {
    i = (i + 1) % videoPathes.size();
    videoView.setVideoPath(videoPathes.get(i));
    // the rest ...
}
```

Comment: This is not working. I have to play 10 videos in a row which are in raw folder how to do it??