# How do I play videos sequentially; one after the other?

Tags: android

I am developing an Android application in which I am reading video links from web services and displaying them in a ListView. I want it so that when I click on any video link it starts playing and at end of that video the next video starts playing automatically (just like a playlist).

Comment: Can you provide some backstory describing what you've researched and what you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

```
        myVideoView.setVideoPath(vidPath);
        myVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        myVideoView.requestFocus();
        myVideoView.start();
        myVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(completionListener);

 OnCompletionListener completionListener=new OnCompletionListener() {



@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mp.stop();
        //list1 is your list.
    i = (i + 1) % list1.size();
         //lstplay is your listview.
    lstPlay.setItemChecked(i, true);
        setup(i); 

}
};
```

Hope this will help you.For your [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8238442), [reference1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16142019/merge-video-blank-frame-issue),[reference2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11560716)